# MeteorJS and Iron:Router error with WebSocket

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm using MeteorJS with Iron:Router on Windows 8.1, I've created a simple meteor project and added Iron:Router library, then copy an example ([Router Controller](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/tree/devel/examples/route_controllers)) but it throws this error.

layot.html

```
<head>
  <title>route_controllers</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<template name="AppLayout">
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/posts">/posts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <article>
      {{> yield}}
    </article>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="Home">
  <h1>Home</h1>
</template>

<template name="PostIndex">
  <h1>Post Index</h1>
</template>
```

layout.js

```
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home'
});

Router.route('/posts', {
  controller: 'PostController',
  action: 'index'
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  ApplicationController = RouteController.extend({
    layoutTemplate: 'AppLayout',

    onBeforeAction: function () {
      this.next();
    },
  });

  HomeController = ApplicationController.extend({
    action: function () {
      this.render('Home');
    }
  });

  PostController = ApplicationController.extend({
    index: function () {
      this.render('PostIndex');
    }
  });
}
```

console.error:

```
 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/sockjs/034/68ih8b52/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line
```

Comment: Try disabling your anti-virus or proxy (if you have one) to see if it solves the issue

Comment: thanks ! that solved it ... do I need add a filter to the anti-virus ?